# How to remove blank line in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

```
- col1  Col2  col3
- 1      A      1
- 2      B      2
- 3      A      1
- 4      B      2
```

I wrote the formula like as shown below

```
Local CurrencyVar colvalue := ToNumber ({storedprocedure;1.col3});

If colvalue = 1 Then
(
    {storedprocedure;1.col2} ;
);

Local CurrencyVar colvalue := ToNumber ({storedprocedure;1.col3});

If colvalue = 2 Then
(
    {storedprocedure;1.col2} ;
);
```

And also tried using text object field making "suppress embedded filed blank line" but still not displaying as required.

Please suggest how can we achieve it.

[Required output(1), As displaying(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/333Dk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not blank line it is the formula that is producing that blank space as there is no data to perform for the formula if `if` condition fails.

To overcome you need to take two sub reports and place them side by side without any gap in detail section.

**Sub report 1:**

Create a formula `@Formula1` and write your first part of the formula

```
Local CurrencyVar colvalue := ToNumber ({storedprocedure;1.col3});

If colvalue = 1 Then
(
    {storedprocedure;1.col2} ;
);
```

Go to record selection formula of the sub report and write below code:

```
{storedprocedure;1.col3}=1
```

**Sub report 2**

Create a formula `@Formula2 and write your first part of the formula

```
Local CurrencyVar colvalue := ToNumber ({storedprocedure;1.col3});

If colvalue = 2 Then
(
    {storedprocedure;1.col2} ;
);
```

Go to record selection formula of the sub report and write below code:

```
{storedprocedure;1.col3}=2
```

Remove borders for sub report

Comment: yes working thank you. One more thing how to set the width of each box dynamically? I want to pass width through C# code for sub report.

Comment: Actually I work on CR as a standalone tool not through C# code... so no idea on how to write code for that